# Duplicated reason of a duplicate choice

Tags: support, close-reasons

When flagging the question, these options are presented to me:

> I am flagging to report this question as...
>
> - spam
>
>   Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose
>   the author's affiliation.
> - rude or abusive
>
>   A reasonable person would
>   find this content inappropriate for respectful discourse.
> - should be closed...
>
>   This question is completely unclear, incomplete,
>   overly-broad, primarily opinion-based or is not about Drupal as
>   described in the help center, and it is unlikely to be fixed via
>   editing.
> - **a duplicate...**
>
>   This question has been asked before and already has an answer.
> - in need of moderator intervention
>
>   A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!

When I'm choosing *should be closed...*, it's showing again the same option as in the previous page, which is:

> - **duplicate of...**
>
>   This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

Is this a simple alias, or a bug?

Is there any difference between choosing one of another, or it's basically the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

You get your privilege to flag way earlier than you get privilege to vote close. This means there need to be entry in flag list for it - so folks can flag even without access to vote menu.

If you will try to cast duplicate flag when you already have a vote to close privilege, **flag will be automatically converted to vote**. Probably it won't even get listed in your flag history. Entry is not removed from flag menu because (that's my guess) people who *just* got voting to close privilege may still have a habit to look for it in flags, so why developers should invest more work in making things harder?

Comment: Thanks, so basically choosing 'duplicate' on the first page would only flag the post and on the second page would vote to close? Is that right?

Comment: @kenorb almost. Flag will be immediately converted to vote anyway. Probably flag will not even get listed on your flag history.